# Get the value of an array as an integer and show on buttons in realtime

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get the number of values in myKeyArray to print as an integer so that whenever a child is added or removed in firebase it updates. Currently it prints the number of values in the array updates correctly but i just want it as an integer too. I have tried myKeyArray.count but this doesn't work

EDIT:

i realised that I should be printing the snapshot.children.allObjects.count which gives me the right value but I then get an error with the if statement when I run the app

the main issue i'm having is with the if statement when it gets the number of arrays from the following node - I want it to say if there are 3 or less in the following node - make the buttons do this or else if there are 4 or more make the buttons do something else but this is giving me an error

```
  let ref = self.ref.child("following").child(uid) //retreives all nodes in the following node
    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        let followingNum = snapshot.children.allObjects.count
        for child in snapshot.children { //build the array of keys
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            myKeyArray.append(key)

        //go through array and grab 4 random names
        var randomKeyArray = [String]()
        let numFollowers = min(4, myKeyArray.count)
        for _ in 0..<numFollowers { //will iterate four times
            let count = myKeyArray.count //get the number of elements
            let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<count) //get a random index for the array
            let randomUserKey = myKeyArray[randomInt]
            randomKeyArray.append(randomUserKey)
            myKeyArray.remove(at: randomInt) //remove that object so it's not selected again 
        }

        //get the name of each user
        let numberOfKeys = randomKeyArray.count
        var names = [String]()
        for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
            let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
            let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
                names.append(name)
                self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)

         //show names on buttons in realtime
         if followingNum <= 3 {
                    self.optionA.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionA.isEnabled = false
                    self.optionB.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.isEnabled = false
                    //repeat for 2 more buttons

                } else if followingNum >= 4 {
                    self.currNames = names
                    self.optionA.setTitle(names[0], for: .normal)
                    self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal) //ERROR here "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"
                   //repeat for 2 more buttons

                }
            })
        }
        }
    })
}
```

I hope this is not too much code but I thought it might be useful for background since i've been stuck trying to update it for a while

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please dit your question and post your code. `if "myKeyArray integer" <= 3 {` it is not valid Swift syntax

Comment: What's the problem with `myKeyArray.count`?

Comment: @LeoDabus yes I understand but I will replace "myKeyArray integer" when i can get name for the number of values in the array (it just wrote it to help see what I would use it for) :)

Comment: @edey if your `myKeyArray` is appended properly and has values in it, then `myKeyArray.count` should be exactly what you need, why doesn't it work?

Comment: your question is unclear show exactly where you have putted your condition. btw "**`myKeyArray.count` but this doesn't work**" it is too vague

Comment: @Vyacheslav when i use myKeyArray.count, instead of printing the number of nodes under the following e.g. 5 it prints "1 1 1 1 1" - maybe I could then convert this to make it a single number?

Comment: Where do you call that, It seems you did `myKeyArray.count` inside the `for `loop? then it would output: 1 2 3 4 5 rather that 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: I have just edited the code above so hopefully that makes it more clear

Comment: your array never gets more than one element. Thats obvious. it prints 1 five times probably

Comment: Is there a way to add up the values in the array then use it in the if statement?

Comment: @edey as Leo says it seems it is doing the loop 5 times but only appending the key the first time. that is why you get 1 1 1 1 1 instead of 1 2 3 4 5 I think. Once you fix that, as long as you call `myKeyArray.count`  after the loop is done then that is what you can use to get your integer

Comment: @edey something is wrong in your `for child` try `print(myKeyArray)` and see if it prints 5 of the exact same thing, meaning there is only 1 key in the array even after the loop is finished. Then it may be a problem with how you get the keys, because it loops 5 times which is correct, but need to figure out why it only adds 1 key to the array

Comment: I realised that I should be printing snapshot.children.allObjects.count instead - this seems to give me what I want, except it gives me a Thread 1 Index out of range error on the buttons when i use it in the if statement (I will update the code above to show) :)

Comment: @edey That sounds like it is because the `ref.observe` is asynchronous so you might be calling the if statement when the count doesn't exist yet if that makes sense. the code doesnt wait for the firebase call basically so if it doesnt finish before the if statement then it will crash. (index out of range) I'll try to whip up a solution

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your error is because where you put your if statement. It is inside the same place where you append `names` and it is a `for` statement. So what you are doing is you are declaring `var names = [String]()` and then  the `if` statement is happening on each iteration, when the name hasn't been added yet, if I am understanding it correctly.

```
//get the name of each user
    let numberOfKeys = randomKeyArray.count
    var names = [String]() //<- empty
    for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
        let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
        let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
            names.append(name) //<- append
            self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)

     //show names on buttons in realtime
     if followingNum <= 3 {
                self.optionA.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                self.optionA.isEnabled = false
                self.optionB.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                self.optionB.isEnabled = false
                //repeat for 2 more buttons

            } else if followingNum >= 4 {
                self.currNames = names
                self.optionA.setTitle(names[0], for: .normal)
                self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal) //ERROR here "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" // only names[0] exists at this point.
               //repeat for 2 more buttons

            }
        })
```

So we need to probably make this a function so we can call it at the right place:

```
func showNames() {
     if followingNum <= 3 {
                self.optionA.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                self.optionA.isEnabled = false
                self.optionB.setTitle("Follow\nat least\n4 friends!", for: .normal)
                self.optionB.isEnabled = false
                //repeat for 2 more buttons

            } else if followingNum >= 4 {
                self.currNames = names
                self.optionA.setTitle(names[0], for: .normal)
                self.optionB.setTitle(names[1], for: .normal) //ERROR here "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"
               //repeat for 2 more buttons

            }

}
```

So it needs to happen after all the iterations for the names, so maybe call it here, just outside and after the loop:

```
  for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
        let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
        let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
            names.append(name)
            self.currIds.append(thisUserKey)
            }
            self.showNames()
```

You may need to declare `followingNum` outside the whole thing:

```
 var followingNum = Int()
```

then update it instead:

```
 self.followingNum = snapshot.children.allObjects.count
```

Alternatively,just make sure that your if statement is not inside the `for` loop. Hope that made sense it should solve the `names[1]` problem. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! I have edited my code to match yours but it looks like when I print(names) just before/after self.showNames  it says there are 0 values so the names.append(name) doesn't save to array which might be why the showNames isn't working? When i print(followingNum) it shows the right number now though :)

Comment: @edey Hmm, try printing names inside the loop right under `names.append(names)` and comment out `self.showNames` and you might be able to catch where  its failing to append the names